# Can't display form inside TabPage in WinForms application

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs

My WinForms application has form that contains several tabs. Inside each tab page i want to have another forms. That's how i add form to tab page:

```
public void InitializeTabs()
{
   // Example #1
   PlaceForm(FirstTabPage, new OneForm(EntryForm, Settings));
            
   // Example #2
   PlaceForm(SecondTabPage, new TwoForm(EntryForm, Settings));
}
```

#### Method `PlaceForm`

```
public void PlaceForm(TabPage tabPage, Form form)
{
    form.TopLevel = false;
    form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    form.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    form.AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Dpi;

    if (!tabPage.Controls.Contains(form))
    {
        tabPage.Controls.Add(form);
        tabPage.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        form.Show();
     }
}
```

Example #1 - works - form added to tab page. But Example #2 - works strangly - if i add existing in project form class to second tab page - form is shown as expected, but when i create new form from wizard
and trying to display it on second tab page - form is not showing.

I finally confused, what i make wrong or where to search solution?

Comment: Are you sure it is wise to put a Form inside a Control? Shouldn't you use a UserControl instead of a Form? If the reason that you want to use a Form is because you also want to show the Form separately, then you could put the UserControl docked in the separate Form.

Comment: If you have already a Form shown in a TabPage, this: `if (!tabPage.Controls.Contains(form))` won't find it, since it's comparing an **Instance** of a Form with a **new Instance** of that Form, so the two won't match and you add a **second Instance** of that Form to the TabPage. You cannot see it because it's shown under the existing. Add `form.BringToFront();` after `form.Show();` to bring it on top. Now, you have **two instances** of the same Form in that TabPage. -- As suggested, replce Forms with UserControls: UserControls also have a Designer. The **Instances** you create still matter.

Comment: Use UserControls with internal fields and controls!